# Can't make users login for long period of time

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have this platform which you can login and do your tests (this is a test link): www.mf.pt.la

I can't understand why this isn't working... first I tried this on top of my config.php file:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 864000);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 864000);
```

Than I tried this with a cookie:

```
$year = time() + 31536000;
if($_POST['remember']=="1")
{
    setcookie("remember_me", $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER], $year);
}
elseif($_POST['remember']=="") 
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) 
    {
        $tendays = time() + 864000;
        setcookie("remember_me", $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER], $tendays);
    }
}
```

None seem to work because after 30mins/1h user is logged out! :(

This is very frustrating because inside this website users are usually getting in a out more than once per day, and having always to login is making me lose users actually! :(

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, so let's see where we are at this point.

After a lot of tests, I have noticed the problem was that I was trying to save an array directly into the cookie and it doesn't work like that. I have searched a lot and created a very simple cookie with name "test" and content "text" and it worked, so if what was working I did created a cookie!

Then I searched for a way to put it working all together on the same cookie instead of save one cookie for each information I needed.

So this is the conclusion. To create the cookie, this is what I've made:

```
$cookie_name = "remember_me";
$userinfo = $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['user_id']."_".$_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['user_type']."_".$_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['name']."_".$_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['email'];
if($_POST['remember']=="1"){
    setcookie($cookie_name, $userinfo, time() + 31536000, '/');
}else{
    setcookie($cookie_name, $userinfo, time() + 864000, '/');
}
```

And to call the cookie this is what I have made:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["remember_me"])) {
    $usercookie = explode("_",$_COOKIE["remember_me"]);
    $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['user_id'] = $usercookie[0];
    $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['user_type'] = $usercookie[1];
    $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['name'] = $usercookie[2];
    $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER]['email'] = $usercookie[3];
}
```

So far, it seems to work, but... let's see if in some more hours the login is done automatically after I enter the website again.

**EDIT 2:**

Just noticed that spaces are saved into cookie as + and @ as %40

**EDIT 3:**

FINALLY! I did it and here's what I did in order to help future users:

First, let's start by creating the cookie. I inserted a new colum in my users table to save a token, and assigned that token as an encription in MD5 to a variable, like this:

```
$tokenuser = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

Once the table was updated, we must create the cookie, and here it is:

```
$cookie_name = "mfrm";
if($_POST['remember']=="1"){
    setcookie($cookie_name, $tokenuser, time() + 31536000, '/');
}else{
    setcookie($cookie_name, $tokenuser, time() + 864000, '/');
}
```

For those who didn't understood that "if" condition, that's simply to check if the user have selected the "checkbox" in order to be remembered "forever" (one year in this case).

So far so good, the next part was the one that was "try and error" until I finally did it! You should put this code BEFORE your headers, because otherwise it might not work and will probably give you an error:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["mfrm"])) {
    $usercookie = $_COOKIE["mfrm"];
}
```

So, this way your variable $usercookie now has the content of your cookie (the unique token we created).

"Later" on your code, you simply do a call to your database, check for which user that token is valid and then just asign user_id and all other things you want in order for user to have his login. :)

I hope whoever sees this can solve the problem, I did a LOT of Google search before I finally get this working.

My suggestion is, do a lot of "print" and "echo" in PHP so you can see where is your problem, if needed stop your code by inserting sleep(2); (where 2 means two seconds)

Good luck! :)

Comment: You cant set $_SESSION with setcookie()

Comment: Are you using sessions anywhere else with different settings regarding lifetime, but the same setting regarding their save_path? If so, those other scripts might trigger deleting of existing session files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't suffice, cookies are saved in user's browser, so every time she connects, you check her cookies and and set set up her session accordingly.

Hope this helps

=== EDIT ===

This may help you: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript

Let's say that the user ID is '12345', and he is logging in
You set the cookie with:

```
setcookie('user_id', '12345', time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

Then, then if the user logs in tomorrow, and his session has expired, you check if his user_id exists in DB from the cookies:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
    // check the user_id in DB and create session if exists
}else{
    // User has no cookies, then he has to login
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

This is a very simple example, so of course, do not just put a user_id in your cookies, but a more rigorous form of authentication, like the last session id and a token you'd have generated.

=== EDIT2 ===

Is 'remember' the name of a checkbox? Because in which case, if it is not checked, $_POST['remember'] is not set. So instead of checking the value of $_POST['remember'], you should check if it is set or not

Assuming that 'remember' is the name of a checkbox:

```
$year = time() + 31536000;
if(isset($_POST['remember']))
{
    setcookie("remember_me", $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER], $year);
}
else
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) 
    {
        $tendays = time() + 864000;
        setcookie("remember_me", $_SESSION[LOGIN_USER], $tendays);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it didn't helped actually because I didn't understood what you mean. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Basically you store cookies on the user's computer
Then every time a user connects, you first check if they've got cookies from you, if they do, the set the session for that particular user, otherwise if they do not, then the user will have to login.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: I thank you very much for your help, which should work, but I can't understand why cookie isn't being created! :(

I mean, I have searched online why, found out that many people have the same problem and tried different solutions, none worked... Cookie isn't simply created and that's it... :(

Comment: No worries :)
Is 'remember_me' a checkbox? Because in which case, if it is not checked, $_POST['remember'] is not set. So instead of checking the value of $_POST['remember'], you should check if it is set or not.

Comment: @nicom974: So if I was to manipulate the cookie value, and change it from user id `12345` to `54321`, then I would automatically be logged in as the latter? You’re not describing what `// check the user_id in DB and create session if exists` is actually supposed to mean – but in the way you described it, the whole thing sounds just very naive and dangerous …

Comment: yeah, I was actually going to say that it is just a very simple example, but forgot. For this, I would of use a long token.

Comment: Guys, thank you all for your generous help. It indeed helped me out in order for me to understand better what to search for and adapt the problem to my specific case. Now, since it seems to work (at least so far, let's see in some more hours from now), now can I encrypt that info and then decrypt it? user_id and user_type?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use a token and avoid saving personal information in cookies :) Don't forget to set this as the Answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Ok, but once again, how can I do that pal? :)

Comment: Ok, I have found this: http://guid.us/GUID/PHP But how can I make this work on my code?

Comment: You don't need guid, just use:
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

And it will do the job. What you could do is to add in your user's table the token used for the session and cookies (ie. $_COOKIES['token'])
So when he is on your website, you can check his token, and log him in automatically if it matches the one in the DB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there must be some tutorials online about sessions, cookies and security with some sample projects. Google is your friend :)

Comment: @nicom974 I thank you once again, but unfortunately something is still not working here... :( This is very, very frustrating! Cookie is there, code is there, so why is that after 30mins or 1h, user just lost his login session and I must login again? This makes no sense for me, something must be destroying the session or something like that, I don't know. :(

Comment: Ok, first of all @nicom974, thank you very much for your patience. Thanks to you I FINALLY did it! :D I will edit my question once again with the explanation of what I did so future users can find the solution. Thank you very much.